# Extract header timestamp of Image message

Tags: ros, timestamp, roscpp, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the extraction of a timestamp from the header of a `sensor_msgs::Image` that easy:

```
void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& imsg) {
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imsg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_16UC1);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }
    
    //get header info
    std_msgs::Header h = imsg->header;
    cout<<h<<endl; //all at once
    cout<<h.stamp<<endl; //specific parts of it
    cout<<h.stamp.sec<<endl;
    cout<<h.stamp.nsec<<endl;
    cout<<h.seq<<endl;

    //do some with it
```

This is the output

```
seq: 11536  //all info
stamp: 1455792836.004090186
frame_id: camera_depth_optical_frame

1455792836.004090186 //stamp
1455792836 //sec
4090186 //nsec
11536 //seq
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227008/extract-header-timestamp-of-image-message/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.

I wouldn't call it *extraction* though. You're basically just accessing the `.header.stamp` member variable.

This of course depends on your message *having* a field of type [Header](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-18**:
How to check if its there to prevent errors, segfaults etc, when trying to access it and its not there?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-18**:
ROS messages in C++ are auto-generated from the `msg` files. The compiler will error-out if you try to use fields that are not part of the struct definition. For dynamically typed languages you'll have to use the facilities of the language to check for presence of fields.